# Exclude target=_blank links

Tags: jquery, href

I have following jquery Expression:

```
$('a').on("click", function (e) {
    window.LoadingPanel.Show();
});
```

How do I exclude all links with target="_blank"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a[target!='_blank']").on("click", function (e) {
    window.LoadingPanel.Show();
});
```

Comment: My Resharper tells me that "!=" is not allowed in CSS3.0. Is this correct instead? "a:not([target='_blank'])"

Comment: This isn't css. It's JavaScript. Resharper must think you're writing css but you're not. My answer is correct if you're writing JavaScript. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
<script>


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a:not([target="_blank"])').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      /* Act on the event */
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[target!='_blank]").on("click", function (e) {    
    window.LoadingPanel.Show();
});
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/